# Парсинг json в Android

Tags: json, php, java, android

Взгляните ребят, что я делаю не так?

```
 try {

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++){

            JSONObject data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            list.setText(data.getJSONArray("price").getString(i)+" "+data.getJSONArray("description").getString(i)+"\n");

        }
```

На сам пакет можно взглянуть здесь http://m.renault-sokol.ru/api/getmodels/

В ответе на экране в приложении ничего нет. Пермишн на интернет есть, запросы шлются, пакет 100% получает эмулятор, но распарсить никак.

Comment: По вышеприведённому URL отдаётся не JSON array, а JSON object.

Comment: Тогда как бы его таким распарсить?

Comment: @falstaf прав. корневой элемент того, что отдается по приведенной ссылке - JSONObject, а не JSONArray

Comment: Вопрос еще открыт?

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте!

Если я правильно понял, то json получается от api-сервера.

В последнее время, для подобных задач пользуюсь библиотеками от square (http://square.github.io/) Для данной - Retrofit (http://square.github.io/retrofit/) и GSON.

Добавление одной строчки кода `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` автоматические преобразует JSON в нужные элементы. Просто, быстро, удобно )

```
Retrofit retrofit = (new Retrofit.Builder())
        .baseUrl(URL_SERVER)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

public void initData() {

GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService .class);

Call<List<Repo>> call = service.listRepos("user");
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Repo>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Repo>> call, Response<List<Repo>> response) {
        for (Repo repo:
                response.body()) {
                adapter.add(repo);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Repo>> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
}
```